# DNS не работает за VPN в Debian 10

Tags: debian, dns, vpn

Устанавливаю cisco-openconnect соединение, пингую сервер по имени... Первые минуту-две пингуется, потом пишет "Name or service not known" если пинговать по имени. А если по IP адресу, то всё нормально продолжает пинговаться. При этом так происходит только с хостами за VPN-ом, остальные пингуются по имени без проблем.

Свежий Debian 10.6 в виртуалке VMWare, установлены только Xfce4, openconnect-manager-gnome. Заметил, что сервис *systemd-resolved* не стартует автоматически с системой, но при запуске его вручную ничего не поменялось - имена за VPN через время перестают определяться.

В Ubuntu, также поставленной в виртуалке такой проблемы не наблюдается.

Делал в Debian такой же файл `/etc/resolv.conf`, как и в убунте, перезапускал  *systemd-resolved* - не помогает.

Из-за чего это происходит? Что и как надо сконфигурировать, чтобы DNS за VPN продолжал работать без сбоев?

[UPDATE]
Вот разница `/etc/resolv.conf` и `resolvectl status` при подключенном VPN. Убунту отпределяет адреса за VPN, дебиан определяет где-то минуту, потом нет (при том что DNS от VPN пингуется):
[image: VPN_conf]

Comment: поставь родной экниконнект клиент от циски, для начала и посмотри как в нем работать будет. спилт тоннелинг для днс у тебя включен? у меня и под виндой бывали глюки на ровном месте на одном пк все ок, на втором только по ип причем сразу, притом политика/тоннельная группа у них общая.

Comment: @Yakov, "спилт тоннелинг" это что? Не знаю включен ли. На хост-машине с Windows OpenConnect работает, как и в убунту. Что-то с DNS в сыром дебиане... хочу понять что

Comment: а настройках асы в тоннельной группе есть опция dns split tonneling когда у тебя только запросы к домену с определенными суффиксами идут через впн, а остальные идут через локальный днс-сервер. незнаю как на убунте с опен коннектом, но на нативном клиенте это работает на винде покрайней мере хорошо. но иногда бывают глюки, видимо связанные с драйверами на хотовой машине. иногда помогает отключение этой опции и направление всех запросов через впн.

Comment: поставь на убунту родного клиента, и на нем отладь, а потом уже мучай сторонние решения.